# FEE error NIKON D90 50mm f/1.8

Tags: lens, nikon

My nikon D90 is showing FEE error on all settings and is not clicking pictures at the moment. Nikon support says the answer lies in page 26 of the User's manual but i didn't find anything helpful. I've used this lens for about a year and this is the first time this has occurred. It works with my kit lens (18-105mm AF/MF). What can be done to reset this?

Comment: Pay NIKON their fee?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually set and lock the aperture fully closed (f/22 on the 50mm) for the D90 to be able to control it electronically.  This is detailed in the first footnote on page 26 of the manual, just like Nikon support said.

Further compatibility details can be found on pages 228 and 229.